# Insert char * with new into a vector C++

Tags: c++, c-strings

I have code sample like below..

```
std::vector<char*> vNameList;//it will be defined globally..



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
CollectName();
  for(int i = 0; i<(int)vNameList.size(); i++)
  {
    printf("\n %s" , vNameList[i]);//Here gabage values are getting printed on console
  }
  return 0;
}

void CollectName()
{
   char *Name = new char[sizeof(NAME)+1];//NAME datatype is defined having size of 32 char

   //processing for Name is performed , which includes assigning Name variable with value..

   //now insert it into vector
   vNameList.push_back(Name);

   delete[] Name; //at this Name value inserted into vector become garbage
}
```

I believe if we initialize char * with new it must be deleted to avoid memory leaks. But this is leading to modifying values from a vector.

Please guide me so that I can correct my code which will give me correct values.

I have some restriction to use Char * only , so suggest way to achieve this using char*.

Comment: Your vector is empty. The loop shouldn't run.

Comment: Why bother solving this in the first place? `std::vector<std::string>` would do just fine.

Comment: Where do you call `CollectName` in your example?

Comment: Dude you want to keep pointers in vector but after that you want to delete their value. Why? Actually if you delete vector correctly ,you can avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can correct your code by deleting the pointers only *after* you're done using them (assuming you actually have code which uses the pointers. Your example code doesn't print anything at all, garbage or otherwise).

But it's usually better design to store character strings in a `std::string` and when you store `std::string`s in a `std::vector`, you no longer need to manage the memory manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the name of array is treated as pointer in c++(or c, it is inherted).

Therefore when you do

```
vNameList.push_back(Name);
```

It inserts the `char *` into vector,i.e the pointer to the first char(ans hence the string) to the vector, but you delete the pointer afterwards , therefore you get junk values. However if you don't delete the pointer , it works just fine as the pointer still exists , but this way you will not free up memory. Therefore : **DONOT USE THIS**

here it is : [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://ideone.com/uMwCnC)

**To avoid this hassle** : you should use

```
std::vector<std::string> vNameList;
```

instead.

Comment: "if you don't delete the pointer, it works just fine" - as long as you find another (reliable) way to fix the leak.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta - I have checked it call to delete is commeted , but will this not cause any memory leaks? I have read that whenever new is used it should deleted.

Comment: @user987316 do you really NEED to use `std::vector<char*>` ?
any good reason why not use `std::vector<std::string>` ? , other wise your best bet will be to copy each char one by one and then use `delete`